# A sequentially compact and metric space is a second countable space.

Tags: general-topology

A sequentially compact and metric space is  a second countable space.

How to prove it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a metric space, it's equivalent sequential compactness with compactness. Also in metric spaces, second countability is equivalent with separability.

Now if a metric space is compact, given an open cover, there exist a finite subcover that covers the space. This inmediately implies that there exist a countable subcover that covers the space which implies separability and therefore second countability.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just need a proof without using that equivalence between  sequential compactness and compactness in a metric space.